# Use of would have in hypothetical conditions

Tags: conditionals

I am still a bit confused about this , can we use would have to indicate a task which someone may have done but you're not sure if they did it or not , or how they did it.
For example in this sentence -

- I wonder how they would have survived when they got attacked.

I could have used second form of verb but that would mean that I was sure they survived , I wanna make it sound like i am not sure if they survived .

Comment: Examples include; How *could* they possibly have survived? How *would* they have managed to survive.

Comment: I want to say , I am not sure if they survived or not , I am just wondering

Comment: Both of the above offer considerable doubt as to their survival. You can add evidence and opinion to these as you are doing. Using would or could is just fine to explain what you cannot believe or wonder about.

Comment: "*I wanna make it sound like i am not sure if they survived.*" Then don't use *would* in the first place: "*I wonder **if** they survived when they got attacked, and, if so, how.*"